# Cannot change the names of specific range of columns of pandas dataframe using ix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to change the names of columns whose original name is a **datetime** type (11.10.2015 00:13) (but the column values stored are integer). For example, I have 6 such columns and I want to replace each column name with a corresponding number from this list [6, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1]. Here is the related part of my code:

```
count_datetime = 6
test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['userid', '12.10.2012 15:30', '02.10.2012 15:30',
                             '22.10.2012 15:30', '11.10.2012 15:30',
                             '15.10.2012 15:30', '20.10.2012 15:30', 'category'])
print test    
test.ix[:,1:count_datetime].columns = range(10, 15)[::-1]
print test
```

This makes no changes, and all original column names are preserved.

What I want to obtain is to have these column names: **userid, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, category**

However, if I get rid of `ix` and attempt to change all column names like this:

```
test.columns = range(10, 18)[::1]
```

then it works. But, this is not I want. I want to update only the ones with datetime column name

Any ideas about what I am missing here?

Comment: what is you desired column-list?

Comment: @MaxU does my update make sense?

Comment: are __all__ your columns of `datetime` dtype?

Comment: @MaxU updating the question, problem is about `ix`, if I do not use it, then it works, but I want to change only part of columns.

Comment: @MaxU see my update please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [12]: test.columns
Out[12]: Index(['userid', '12.10.2012 15:30', '02.10.2012 15:30', '22.10.2012 15:30', '11.10.2012 15:30', '15.10.2012 15:30', '20.10.2012 15
:30', 'category'], dtype='object')

In [13]: cols = test.columns.tolist()

In [14]: test.columns = cols[:1] + list(map(str, np.arange(count_datetime, 0, -1))) + cols[count_datetime+1:]

In [15]: test.columns
Out[15]: Index(['userid', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', 'category'], dtype='object')

In [16]: test
Out[16]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [userid, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, category]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why this is not working: `test.ix[:,1:count_datetime]` ? Because it is changing the local copy?